# Is there a way to make this loop more efficient?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a Google Sheet where I'm compiling an inventory. I've noticed a bunch of mathematical errors recently, so I decided to cut down on the mental addition and build an Apps Script loop that adds two columsn and resets the first column for me. But because I'm using a getValue in basically every loop, it's a very time-intensive process.

I tried looking for ways to write to arrays, etc, but this is my first foray into Google Sheets rather than Excel.

Here's the whole function:

```
function Update() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name');


 for (var x = 2; x < 905; x++) {


  var range1 = sheet.getRange([x],7);

  var num1 = range1.getValue();

  var range2 = sheet.getRange([x],8)

  var num2 = range2.getValue();


  range2.setValue(num1 + num2)

  range1.setValue ('0')

  }
}
```

It's working correctly, but it's really slow and I'd appreciate any tips on how to make this more efficient.

Comment: use getRange() to get the range you want to look at and then iterate over it using JavaScript. This will drastically reduce the number of calls to the server and lead to much better performance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function Update() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Name');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,7,904,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    vA[i][1]=vA[i][0]+vA[i][1];
    vA[i][0]=0;
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: This is a good example. Avoid lookups in the loop. Just get all data and loop through the values, update the array of values and write back (setValues) in 1 call.

Comment: Yeap this is how I would go about it. Much more efficient to get all data in one shot and then just loop through the results. (Rather than fetching the data every time it is needed.)

Comment: Answers which explain how code works are better than ones without, especially for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

As Cooper's answer illustrates, you want to use the batch `Range` methods `getValues` and `setValues` to manipulate a JavaScript array, per ["best practices"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

An improvement is to use `Array` class methods, to reduce nested property accessing, such as [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (return an array based on the source array) or [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (do something for every element in the source array). These class methods provide your callback function with the current element, index, and source array as function arguments, in case they are needed.

When you want short-circuit behavior (stop processing once some condition is met), the traditional index-based `for` loop is still king.

```
function processArray() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = wb.getSheetByName('Name');

  const startRow = 2, endRow = 905;
  const startCol = 7, numCols = 2;
  const rg = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, endRow - startRow + 1, numCols);

  // Construct a new array based on the source array.
  const result = rg.getValues().map(function (row) {
    return [ 0, row[0] + row[1] ];
  });
  // (In this case we haven't changed the dimensions, so we could re-use `rg` .)
  if (result.length) {
    // sheet.getRange(someRow, someCol, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
    rg.setValues(result);
  }
}
```

(Note that currently Apps Script does not support the block-scope use of [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), just the reassignment protection)

Comment: Any benefit to using .map instead of just getting the range tehhowch? (Or are you just showing off. :D)

Comment: Thanks for that example.  I have to admit I tend to avoid those methods.

Comment: @New_2_Code ?? The range is acquired (as `rg`). The values from that range are also acquired, but (since OP isn't doing anything else with them) they aren't stored in a variable before they are acted on. Example code for writing the computed values to a *different* range is provided, just commented out. The major difference from Cooper's answer is the number of property accesses per row - 8 vs 2. Probably the performance difference due to the property access alone is not too great, but whichever engine is running the code may have its own optimizations for `map` and the other Array methods.