# Need to make Loop more efficient in google appscript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am comparing values in google sheet and based on the result adding a result in the one column.

But sheet have over 3000 rows which make code slow as I am looping through each line.

```
function UpdateReadyLINE() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ORDER SHEET");
    var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();

    for(var i = 2; i <= LastRow ; i++){
        var PendingTotal = sheet.getRange(i,10,1,1).getValue();
        var StockAginstLine = sheet.getRange(i,20,1,1).getValue();
        if(PendingTotal==StockAginstLine){
            const time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy");
            sheet.getRange(i,27,1,1).setValue("Ready");
            sheet.getRange(i,33,1,1).setValue(time);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make this loop more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527841/is-there-a-way-to-make-this-loop-more-efficient)

Comment: I am comparing value, so I am not sure if this will help in my case

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function UpdateReadyLINE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("ORDER SHEET");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy");
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[9] == r[19]) {
      sh.getRange(i + 2,27).setValue("Ready");
      sh.getRange(i + 2,33).setValue(ts);
    }
  })
}
```

While being more efficient the following script has the potential for messing up formulas

```
function UpdateReadyLINE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("ORDER SHEET");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy");
  let aa = sh.getRange( 2,27,sh.getLastRow() -1).getValues();
  let ag = sh.getRange( 2,33,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[9] == r[19]) {
      aa[i] = "Ready";
      ag[1] = ts;
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2,27,aa.length,1).setValues(aa);
  sh.getRange(2, 33, ag.length,1).setValues(ag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- When `getValue` and `setValue` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When your script is modified, how about the following patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, only Google Spreadsheet service is used.

```js
function UpdateReadyLINE() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ORDER SHEET");
  var values = sheet.getRange("J2:T" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var { aa, ag } = values.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == r.pop()) {
      var row = i + 2;
      o.aa.push(`AA${row}`);
      o.ag.push(`AG${row}`);
    }
    return o;
  }, { aa: [], ag: [] });
  if (aa.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRangeList(aa).setValue("Ready");
  sheet.getRangeList(ag).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy"));
}
```

- When this script is run, first, the values are retrieved from columns "J" to "T" by one call. And, the range list is created. Using the range list, `Ready` and `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy")` are put.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Sheets API is used. So, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function UpdateReadyLINE() {
  var sheetName = "ORDER SHEET";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy");
  var { values } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, `'${sheetName}'!J2:T${lastRow}`);
  var data = values.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    if (r[0] == r[10]) {
      var row = i + 2;
      ar.push({ range: `'${sheetName}'!AA${row}`, values: [["Ready"]] }, { range: `'${sheetName}'!AG${row}`, values: [[date]] });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, spreadsheetId);
}
```

- When this script is run, first, the values are retrieved from columns "J" to "T" by one API call. And, the request body is created. Using the request body, `Ready` and `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5.30", "dd/MMM/yyyy")` are put.
- When the Spreadsheet is large, when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced rather than the Spreadsheet service is used a little. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)